# Link column headings from table 1 to a parent category in table 2 for report filters

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

Gurus,

I have  2 tables and i would link the column

Table 1

```
Name Process1 Process2 Process3 Process4

joe1     1        3         2      4

Joe2     0        2         4      2

joe3     3        2         2      2
```

I have a visual based on the above table. I have one more table

Table 2

```
Group     Process

ABC       Process1

ABC       Process2

XYZ       Process3

XYZ       Process4
```

I would like to set a filter on table 2 - group , so if the user clicks ABC only the process 1 and Process 2 shows up in the Visual of TABLE 1 values.

How do i make this happen?

currently i am struggling - I have looked at several options

1. I am taking this excel file to powerBI and then taking the powerbi visual to powerapp.
2. if i could get the link then i can use filter on page option in powerbi to filter based on GROUP from table 2 so my table1 visual changes based on selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by un-pivoting your "Table1" Data and using Matrix as a visual. Steps are give below-

**Step-1:** Go to Power Query window by selecting the "Transform Data" from Home menu.

**Step-2:** Select the "Name" column in **table1** and apply Un pivot other columns as shown in the below image-

[image]

The output will be as below-

[image]

**Step-3:** Get back to report by clicking "Close & Apply" button.

**Step-4:** Create a many to many relation between your table1 and table2 using column Group-Attribute.

**Step-5:** Add a Matrix visual and add columns from Table1 as below-

[image]

**Step-6:** Create Slicer using Group column from Table2

Here is the output for selecting different gorup-

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much..it works great. A important point is that i  need the data in Table1 to be in that same format - because i use R to get the visual in powerbi. That particular visual needs the data in wide format. How do i retain the table 1 in the same format and still get the relationship.

Comment: if you have other use of that Table1, just duplicate the table fisrt and then apply all steps on new table for this separate presentation.